# select from SQL array random one per day

Tags: php, sql

How can select from SQL array random one per day?

```
$list=$DB->query("SELECT * FROM belltime")
foreach($list as $txt){
echo $txt->text;
}
```

$list is an array.I want select one item randomly from $list per day.
means everyday only one item randomly selected from $list.

Comment: Arrays are not a standard SQL type.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's a PHP array of the query results.

Comment: Use `array_random()`

Comment: Or use `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1` in the query.

Comment: No need to fetch all results, using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` would give you 1 random record. But this will change for every time you run the query, so you need to store it somewhere if you want that 1 record to show for the entire day.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1` is very inefficient and this is noticable on large datasets.

Comment: You want to run the query only once per day? Or multiple times a day? If the latter, you want the query to return the same value throughout the day? And randomly really means randomly? If the query happens to pick the same text today as it did yesterday that is fine with you? What is your DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `CURDATE()` function you can get a random value daily.

Because   `CURDATE()` function of its changes on a daily basis , In the function `RAND(CURDATE())` daily change random is applied .

You can use the following code:

```
$list=$DB->query("SELECT * FROM belltime ORDER BY  RAND(CURDATE()) LIMIT 1");
        foreach($list as $val){
        echo $val;
        }
```

> RAND(seed):For more information go to click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_rand.asp).
>
> CURDATE():For more information go to click [here](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/func_now.asp.html).